# Getting and highlighting specific location of a specific row in a textarea input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating an application to check the rows that have less comma splits in a given text in textarea.
I am trying to create some red dot indicators to highlight the lines/rows that have less comma splits compared to majority of other rows.
The red dots should be located near the left border of the textarea input and their locations should be inline with the error rows.
I have tried the following code but error dots are appearing at the wrong locations not in concordant with the problematic row line;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Comma Count Checker</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fs/0.18.0/fs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Comma Count Checker</h1>

  <textarea id="textareaInput"></textarea>

  <div id="outputDiv"></div>

  <button onclick="checkCommaCount()">Check Comma Count</button>

  <style>
    .error-dot {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      background-color: red;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    function checkCommaCount() {
      // Get the text from the textarea input
      const text = document.getElementById('textareaInput').value;

      // Create an empty array to store the errors
      const errors = [];

      // Split the text into rows
      const rows = text.split('\n');

      // Get the expected number of commas per row
      const expectedCommaCount = rows[0].split(',').length - 1;

      // Iterate over the rows and check the comma count
      for (let i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
        const row = rows[i];
        const commaCount = row.split(',').length - 1;

        if (commaCount !== expectedCommaCount) {
          // Add the error to the errors array
          errors.push(i);
        }
      }

      // Get the textarea element
      const textarea = document.getElementById('textareaInput');

      // Create a red dot for each error
      for (const error of errors) {
        const errorDot = document.createElement('div');
        errorDot.classList.add('error-dot');

        // Get the height of the problematic row
        const rowHeight = textarea.offsetTop + textarea.scrollHeight * (error - 1);

        // Set the top position of the red dot to the height of the problematic row
        errorDot.style.top = `${rowHeight}px`;

        // Append the red dot to the textarea's parent element
        document.getElementById('textareaInput').parentNode.appendChild(errorDot);
      }

      // Display a message in the output div
      const outputDiv = document.getElementById('outputDiv');
      outputDiv.innerHTML = `<h2>Comma count check complete.</h2>`;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Suppose that the following is my input in textarea;

Kakamega,Kitui,Arusha\n
20,30,35\n
31,44,76\n
45,28\n
67,89,109

It can be seen that the second last row is problematic.

Please help me on how I should have approached this problem.

Comment: `const rowHeight = rows[error].getBoundingClientRect().top;` - your `rows` there are only string values, not HTML elements. You can't call `getBoundingClientRect` on a string.

Comment: Ooh I see. I have approached it with `checkCommaCount()` but am getting error dots tag at the wrong location; see my updated question;

Comment: `const rowHeight = textarea.offsetTop + textarea.scrollHeight * (error - 1);` - that also makes little sense. `offsetTop` is just the offset the textarea _itself_ has regarding its parent node; and  no one is scrolling your textarea while you are performing this check. Plus your `errors` variable contains only the _faulty_ rows, so any rows that do not have any errors, you would leave out of the position calculation here to begin with.

Comment: Would it not be much easier, if you used single-line input fields for this, instead of a textarea? Split your content into lines, create & populate a text input field for each line. And if there is an error in that line - then insert an element before that particular input. If you put each input - and possible error marker - into a div wrapper, then you won't have to do any complex position calculations at all. The user will still be able to edit the individual lines, and if you need the whole thing as one text string at the end, you can still concatenate with a line break again.

Comment: But that is not my intention since my main goal is to create an upload, get the data in that textarea so that I can preview and highlight the locations of problematic rows and make changes before saving the upload.

Comment: Doing this with a textarea will be way more complex though. For starters, you don't know how many lines in the textarea one "line" of your text will actually take - it might break into two or more lines, if it gets wider than the textarea. (And you want the user to be able to make _edits_, so you can't say that case won't ever occur to begin with.) And then the height of your textarea content might also get higher, than the textarea itself - which means you would have to move all your already positioned markers up by a negative amount of the current `scrollTop` value of the textarea.

Comment: @CBroe suggestion of separate input elements would let you do exactly as you have just described (by concatenating the inputs' values once they are all checked as OK). Could you explain further why this would not be suitable?